# UpdateProgress control should show progressing until code executes

Tags: c#, asp.net

`UpdateProgress` control should show progressing until code executes.

I have set of code inside `button_click()`, progress bar should progress until code executes.

I can use `Thread.sleep(5000)`, but my code takes more time and it varies from one request to another request. How can I resolve this? Please help me out.

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server"     
                    AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="center">
                <img alt="" src="loader.gif" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div align="center">
            <h1>Click the button to see the UpdateProgress!</h1>

            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
                 Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Button handler code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```